# Background video of div not playing on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, elementor

ISSUE

Background video of a div on the homepage of my website was playing fine on Firefox & IE but not on google chrome. At the outset, it seemed liked a caching issue so I cleared the cookies and the cache and it did work, but only on some computers. On others, it still didn't!!

The error from the console:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided 
('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin 
('http://example.com').
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE & FIX (Specific to Elementor Pro Page Builder - Wordpress)

The error on Chrome's console pointed towards the source of the video (YouTube - on https) and the destination (my test server - on http), to be the issue. I changed that too.

And while I was doing this, I also happened to notice an unexpected css class attached to the container of the video. This particular class 'elementor-invisible' was making the container invisible. Setting it to visible seems to have solved my issue.

I also changed the YouTube video url from https to http since that too was another suspect.

Things look good now.